# UILabel's in static cells disappear after Larger Text is enabled from Accessibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility

I have an iOS application that has four tabs, one of which has a `UITableView` with static cells. While the application is open, if the user goes to the Accessibility settings and toggles (whether it be from on to off or off to on) Large Text, and returns to the applciation, the static cells' text labels disappear. I tried reloading the table when `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` was thrown, creating a category of UIApplication to disable Large Text in the manner below,

```
@implementation UIApplication (FontSize)

- (NSString *)preferredContentSizeCategory {
    return UIContentSizeCategoryMedium;
}

@end
```

but none of them worked.

One other behavior worth noting is that disappearing labels belong to the cells that were loaded before the settings change. If a cell was not loaded before the settings change, its label appears just fine.

Comment: any update on this? I am getting this bug also